# Network: Longest prefix matching

Tags: networking

A router (IPv4)

```
Destination             Interface
0.0.0.0/0               m0
172.58.128.0/17         m1
172.58.128.0/19         m2 
172.58.160.0/19         m3
```

I need choose which interface is correct.
I did so:

```
172.58.218.80 m2
172.58.165.90 m3
172.58.124.36 m1
172.58.169.18 m3  
172.58.155.112 m2
172.59.12.142 m0
```

Can anyone check if I did this right? Beacuse I do not really understand the "longest prefix match".

How can I know the address is been "match" in the routing table?

Thanks

---

Thanks. **resmon6**

So Step1 convert it to binary.

```
10101100.00111010.10000000.00000000 172.58.128.0/17  
10101100.00111010.10000000.00000000 172.58.128.0/19         
10101100.00111010.10100000.00000000 172.58.160.0/19
```

Step2 use subnet mask to get the prefix.

```
10101100.00111010.1    is the prefix for 172.58.128.0/17
10101100.00111010.100  is the prefix for 172.58.128.0/19
10101100.00111010.101  is the prefix for 172.58.160.0/19
```

Step3

```
10101100.00111010.11011010.01010000 172.58.218.80 
10101100.00111010.10100101.01011010 172.58.165.90 
10101100.00111010.01111100.00100100 172.58.124.36 
10101100.00111010.10101001.00010010 172.58.169.18  
10101100.00111010.10011011.01110000 172.58.155.112 
10101100.00111011.00001100.10001110 172.59.12.142

-------------------------------------------------------- 
10101100.00111010.1 
10101100.00111010.100 
10101100.00111010.101
```

So it means

```
172.58.218.80 m1
172.58.165.90 m3
172.58.124.36 m0
172.58.169.18 m3
172.58.155.112 m2
172.59.12.142 m0
```

Can you help me to check it is correct now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

When you have a routing table the prefix is the route itself converted to binary, matching only the number of bits in the subnet mask. So if you take this routing table

```
192.168.100.0/24
192.168.0.0/16
```

and convert it to binary you get

```
11000000.10101000.01100100.00000000   192.168.100.0/24
11000000.10101000.00000000.00000000   192.168.0.0/16
```

Then you use the subnet mask to get the prefix. Use the number of bits in the subnet mask, starting from the left.

```
11000000.10101000.01100100   is the prefix for 192.168.100.0/24
11000000.10101000            is the prefix for 192.168.0.0/16
```

Now when you are choosing a route for a destination you will convert your destination IP to binary and choose the route with the longest prefix that matches.

You can see that the destination for 192.168.100.50 matches both route prefixes so it chooses the longer prefix of 192.168.100.0/24

```
192.168.100.50/32 11000000.10101000.01100100.00110010
-----------------------------------------------------
192.168.100.0/24  11000000.10101000.01100100
192.168.0.0/16    11000000.10101000
```

I know subnetting can be confusing at first but I don't want to do your work for you. I will tell you that it's not correct.

Comment: Hi resmon6. Can you help me to check if I did it correct now. Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to match the entire subnet? For example, if the destination for your example was `192.168.101.50` instead, would it it still match to the longer prefix of `192.168.100.0/24`, or would it choose the `192.168.0.0/16` because it did not match the entire prefix of the first one?

Answer (score 10):

**Brief intro:**

Each packet arriving at a router has a destination IP address. Router forwards the packet on a particular interface by matching the address against a list of routing table entries, commonly referred to as subnet prefixes.

The challenge comes when an IP address matches against more than one such prefix. In this case the longest matching prefix is selected.

Longest prefix combines hierarchical approach of routing table with flexibility to handle packets to different destinations uniquely.

---

The procedure mentioned above is correct. But you need not always work in binary. There is a simpler approach to this.

**Step 1: For each interface, identify the address ranges as follows.**

m1: 172.58.128.0/17

> Consider 15 (32-17) bits from right, make them all 0 to get the
>   starting IP address. Make them all 1 to get the ending IP address. The
>   1's in the last octet yields 255 (8 1's). The 1's in the 3rd octet yields 127 (7 1's) &
>   adding this to the netmask of 128, we get 255.
>
> - Starting -> 172.58.128.0
> - Ending -> 172.58.255.255

m2: 172.58.128.0/19

> Consider 13 (32-19) bits from right, make them all 0 to get the
>   starting IP address in this range & make them all 1 to get the ending
>   IP address (3rd octet: 128 + 31 [5 1's] = 159)
>
> - Starting -> 172.58.128.0
> - Ending -> 172.58.159.255

m3: 172.58.160.0/19

> - Starting -> 172.58.160.0
> - Ending -> 172.58.191.255

**Step 2: Construct a simple table with the interface ranges as follows.**

[image: nterface range description table]

Note:

- Longer the horizontal division (as in case of m2 & m3) more specific
  the prefix is & should be chosen in case of overlapping ranges.
- The ranges of m2 & m3 are independent (i.e., don't overlap) but both overlap with the range of m1.
- All in all, the m1, m2 & m3 overlap with the default range of m0 (which includes all IP addresses).

**Step 3: Match the given IP addresses against the correct range.**

```
    172.58.218.80  -> m1
    172.58.165.90  -> m3
    172.58.124.36  -> m0
    172.58.169.18  -> m3
    172.58.155.112 -> m2
    172.59.12.142  -> m0
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the thorough documentation there, clearly you know your stuff :)

Comment: Clear and precise. Thanks :)